# How to index all catalogue from Netflix, Hotstar and other OTT platforms

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, pyspider

I am working on a project wherein I need to catalog all the movie and TV show titles from major OTT platforms such as Netflix, Hotstar, Hulu, and such. The metadata collected would be title name, genre, released date, available on.

Further, any automated way to update my list every day with latest movies/shows added?

I did a research of my own and understand that neither of these platforms offers their API hence that option's closed. **Scraping** the titles is illegal I believe as it may harm their servers.

What are my options to do so?

The basic idea is to display what movie is available on which platform.

There are few apps for that like JustWatch, Reelgood. I don't understand how are they so updated. Are they **scraping** or anything.

Nevertheless, I need to understand the legal way of extracting the data.

Thanks

Comment: I’m no lawyer, but to access those catalogs you need to agree to terms of use that in most cases, if not all, will state that you will not do this.

Comment: You're trying to do something that Netflix *really doesn't* want you to do - why do you thing there's no publicly available catalog? Or no public API? You can use screen scraping, perhaps using Selenium, but Netflix is going to detect this at some point and blacklist you.

Comment: There are two parts to this; a) Netflix doesn't want to pay for compute time, power and hardware for screen scrapers. It's not about harming their servers, it's about not using servers for nothing. A 5% load on 100 servers is 5 servers going to waste, and Netflix has a lot more than 100 servers. b) Netflix *doesn't* want you to subscribe only when something interesting appears. They want you to keep paying every month

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well said

Answer (score 0):

Websites/ Projects like reelgood and similiar pages rely on third-party APIs for the most part.

For netflix and hulu there are no public APIs (anymore). (For netflix the (first-party) API is only available for partners)

[This article about the shutdown of the public netflix API also mentions alternatives and an API for Hulu.](https://rapidapi.com/blog/directory/netflix/) If you decide to take advantage of such third-part APIs do it at our own risk.

There are also paid services such as [guidebox](https://www.guidebox.com/) providing APIs.

Comment: can't we scrape if it's performed in an interval without affecting their server?

Comment: It may not be 'affecting' them on a great scale but at some point it's a cost. And a cost that doesn't provide any benefits i.e. an investment is lost money. Also are your sure everyone would be nice when scraping pages?